# Find $a$ so that $a(e^{-2x}-e^{-3x})$ is a probability density function.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, density-function

> Let 
>   $f(x) = a(e^{-2x}-e^{-3x}),$
>   for $x\geq 0$, and $f(x) = 0$ elsewhere.
>   (a) Find $a$ so that $f(x)$ is a probability density function.
>   (b) What is $P(X\leq 1)$?

[Image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FKIyG.jpg)

If it is possible, please show me the detail steps how to solve the first question.

Thank you very very much!

Comment: [Learn](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 5):

$a$ is determined by the equation:
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x) \ dx = 1$$So for this problem:$$a\int_{0}^\infty e^{-2x}-e^{-3x}\  dx = 1$$Now you can solve for $a$.

For the second question, $$P(X\le 1)=\int_{0}^1 f(x) \ dx$$
Plug the values in and you can solve for the probability.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: $a)$ to be a density function, it must be : $\displaystyle \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x)dx = 1$. Split the integral.

$b)$ $P(X\leq 1) = \displaystyle \int_{-\infty}^1 f(x)dx= \displaystyle \int_{0}^1 f(x)dx$